# Node.js synchronization on writing to a csv file

Tags: node.js, file, express, synchronization

I worked on a system, where each request and params were logged to a csv file.

While writing to file, I was using a `lock` for synchronization.

How does synchronization works in node.js ?

if I want to log requests to a file, lets say time based csv files, do i need to lock it?

Comment: If you use something like: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position you don't need to lock the file. JS is single-threaded and will **block** until that call ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I spent a while reading node.js source code. If you use something like `fs.appendFile`, you'll eventually land here (in C++):

```
  if (cb->IsFunction()) {
    ASYNC_CALL(write, cb, fd, buf, len, pos)
    return;
  }
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_file.cc#L681

`write` is plain old POSIC write, and is **not** guaranteed to be atomic (as opposed to `pwrite`). Nothing terrible will happen, but lines might mix up if you call `appendFile` again before the previous call has completed.

You should use `fs.createWriteStream`, which will make sequential POSIX writes (it will keep an internal buffer with data not yet written). This will guarantee that data is written precisely in the order you wrote to the stream.

Comment: and is `fs.createWriteStream` atomic? does it handle concurrency? will it cause performance issue?

Comment: `createWriteStream` will only make 1 write at a time: if you append while data is being written, it will go to a buffer. If anything, it will reduce the number of syscalls and improve performance.

Comment: I would argue any forced synchronous calls would do anything but improve performance as requests now get blocked while waiting to write to the locked file.